# How to get the data value from a list item, using jquery, when it is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have some Html like:

```
<div id="adiv">
    <ul>
            <li data-id="3">Cat</li>
            <li data-id="4">Dog</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

What I wanted was to alert the data-id value when the user clicks the list item.

In jquery I tried:

```
$('li').click(function () {
        alert(this.attr('data-id'));
    });
```

Throws an exception though. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix?

Exception is: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'text'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `attr` function is a member of the `jQuery` object, which means you need to call `$()` on `this`:

```
$('li').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, this would probably be a better method yet:

```
$('li').click(function () {
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Comment: that's correct, also remember that jQuery provides a `.data()` method: http://api.jquery.com/data/